# Формат даты внутри переменной

Tags: php, дата

У меня дата идет внутри переменной $var из формы через POST запрос в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД пытаюсь его преобразовать и вывести его  таким образом

```
$var = $_POST['appdate'] ;
$var = substr_replace($var, null, 0, 3);
$var = strtotime($var) ;
echo $var ;
```

Выводит цифры подряд ... Подскажите пожалуйста выход

Comment: А что вы хотите получить в результате преобразования? В каком формате дату хотите видеть?

Comment: Visman, ДД-ММ-ГГГГ (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если правильно понял о входящих данных, то

```
<?php
$var = '2017-06-12';
$var = strtotime($var); // преобразование строки в  timestamp
$var = date('d-m-Y', $var); // преобразование  timestamp в строку нужного формата
var_dump($var);
```

Выводит

```
string(10) "12-06-2017"
```

UPD Вариант с использованием класса [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2017-06-12');
var_dump($date->format('d-m-Y'));
```

Выводит

```
string(10) "12-06-2017"
```

Comment: BINGO ! Всё верно спасибо )