# Приведение даты/времени к формату и обратно

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос следующий - как привести дату/время к определённому формату, а после "выдернуть" из него дату/время.

Как получить дату в нужно формате я знаю:

```
date('Ymd\THis\Z') //формат yyyymmddThhmmssZ
```

А как имея, например, `20170614T090000`, получить хотя бы обычный strottime?

Comment: Решено. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Работает и это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678178/186083

Comment: задан 33 минуты назад, ответ дан 28 минут назад....разница 5 мин - еще одно доказательство того, что поколению нынче в начале проще написать во все Q&A, а только потом начать что-то искать..... если вообще начинают искать)

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date_create_from_format('Ymd\THis\Z', '20170614T090000');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```