# Переформатировать дату

Tags: php

Есть дата в формате `1/2/2018` `(2 января 2018)`, т.е. `м/д/г`. Как переформатирвать эту дату в `2018-01-02`, `гггг-мм-дд`.

Вроде как простой вопрос, но пока у самого не получается.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Формат даты внутри переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678175/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: @Visman ну похожый вопрос и ответ, но я его сразу не смог найти поэтому задал как новый вопрос

Comment: Не надо отвечать на комментарии такого формата, они формируются автоматически движком сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так?

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("1/2/2018"));
```

Comment: Спасибо всем кто ответил

Answer (score 1):

1. Создаем объект даты с помощью метода DateTime::createFromFormat (http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php)
2. Форматируем дату с помощью DateTime::format (http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php)

Как задать формат смотрим тут:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '1/2/2018');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Методов много, один из них:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('1/2/2018');
$new_date_format = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
print_r($new_date_format);
/*2018-01-02*/
```