# Как сменить формат даты при выводе её на экран из БД

Tags: php, sql-server

В БД формат времени в таблице прописан "2018-03-26 09:24:01", делаю запрос к БД и вывожу данные на экран средствами PHP и получаю "Mar 26 2018 9:24AM". Можно это как то исправить и получать даты в формате 2018-03-26 09:24:01?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Comment: покажите код, где вы выводите

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678175/186083

Comment: В БД  формат ячейки у вас указан DATATIME ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут есть полный перечень фукций MYSQL по форматированию дат:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Наиболее распространенные варианты форматирования:

```
#STR_TO_DATE - приведение строки к формату:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Mar 26 2018 9:24AM',"%M %d %Y %h:%i%p")AS dateFormat;
# на выход -> 2018-03-26 01:38:11

#DATE_FORMAT - приведение даты к формату
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('20190206195959',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S") AS dateFormat;
# на выход -> 2019-02-06 19:59:59

#Приведение timestamp к формату
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('1522057091') ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S" ) AS dateFormat;
# на выход -> 2018-03-26 01:38:11
```

Comment: Нашел: Раскоментировал строчку в php.ini:
mssql.datetimeconvert = On
и установить значение в Off
Теперь показывает значение SQL сервера

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_date = strtotime('Mar 26 2018 9:24AM');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $your_date);
```